# exception: start and end within same entity (not working)

Tags: xml, xsd

I'am trying to create simple xml format for icecream as root element and flavour and size as child. But there is this error:-->

> (XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
>   false)

occuring even though I added the same closing pair tags. Any help is appreciated.

My `xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <icecream xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="icecream.xsd">
        <flavour>Vanilla</flavour>
        <size>M</size>
    </icecream>
```

xsd file `icecream.xsd`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="icecream">
    <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="flavour">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="Vanilla"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="StrawBerry"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="Blackcurrent"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Butter Scotch"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element> 
            <xs:element name="size">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="S"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="M"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="L"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Your posted XSD is missing a closing tag for the `xs:schema` root element.  Is that also true of your actual XSD?

Comment: I added </xs:schema> at the end of xsd.But new error popped up -->> The content of '#AnonType_icecream' is invalid.  Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.) ....

Comment: You've now corrected one in a series of errors.  Perhaps you should try a bit more on each remaining error and only post when you're truly stuck.

Comment: I fixed it thanks... I wrote complexType instead of simpleType by mistake.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out.  Cheers.